# $|a\alpha-b\beta|\leq|a-b|+|\alpha-\beta|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

It may be the case that this is extremely trivial to prove, but I just cannot see it. I want to prove this:

$|a\alpha-b\beta|\leq|a-b|+|\alpha-\beta|$

for $0\leq a,\alpha,b,\beta\leq1$

I think it is also the case that

$|a\alpha-b\beta|\leq|a-b + \alpha-\beta|$

I actually THINK these might hold because I cannot provide any counter example.

Any kind of help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Also, the second inequality does not hold. Take strictly positive $a, \alpha$ such that $1\geq a+\alpha=b$ and $\beta=0$. You get $a\alpha\leq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the $\triangle$ inequality: $|a\alpha - b\beta| = |a\alpha - a\beta + a\beta - b\beta|\le |a||\alpha - \beta|+|\beta||a-b|\le |a-b|+|\alpha-\beta|$

Comment: I'm an idiot :)) thanks a lot

Comment: You are fine, no worry....